# Is it exists a pdf release from google for the android official tutorial?

Tags: android

Can be found the following tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/index.html
in pdf format?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. That being said, Google does not distribute their developer documentation in PDF.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will close the question.